# Android: Send a local image using MMS

Tags: android

I have a set of jpg's stored in my app's drawable folder. I'd like to be able to let users press a button that allows them to send one of these jpg's. I've figured out that I can use an ACTION_SEND intent, but I am having trouble getting the jpg in my drawable folder attached to the intent. I've read a few other forum posts and it sounds like the way to go is to get my jpg saved onto the user's external sd card and then refer to it there. How do I copy the jpg from my app's drawable folder onto the user's external sd card?

Comment: Have you tried suggested approach?

Answer (score 0):

To copy image from resources to the image file in the Pictures directory on SD card you can use following approach:

```
Bitmap resourceImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.resource_image1);       
File externalStorageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "resource_image1.jpg");
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
resourceImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
byte b[] = bytes.toByteArray(); 

try 
{
    externalStorageFile.createNewFile(); 
    OutputStream filoutputStream = new FileOutputStream(externalStorageFile); 
    filoutputStream.write(b); 
    filoutputStream.flush(); 
    filoutputStream.close();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
}
```

Then you can specify it as image attachment in ACTION_SEND intent.

Comment: Ok so it looks like the image is compressed to a bitmap and then a new OutStream file is created with the bitmap and then attached to the intent.  Can you explain why a bitmap and OutputStream file are needed?  Is this still the best way to attach an image?